# SilverLight Get control Value inside Combo Box

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am working on silverlight and I am new in it, I have a combox box,inside which I have a checkbox and textbox. I want to get the value of these controls on button click, How can I do this in SilverLight?
This is my ComboBox

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Type" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,8,-2,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="28" Padding="3">
                        <ComboBoxItem>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="105" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="true" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="All" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Style="{x:Null}" FontSize="11"/>                              
                            </Grid>
                        </ComboBoxItem>

                        <ComboBoxItem>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="105" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="true" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="General" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Style="{x:Null}" FontSize="11"/>                              
                                <TextBox Text="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="11" Padding="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>                                   
                            </Grid>
                        </ComboBoxItem>                     
                        </ComboBox>
```

User have option to select multiple values 
I am using MVVM pattern

Comment: also try linking to the ComboBoxItem IsSelected to the CheckBox IsChecked   

<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your ComboBox Items are unchanging, you can give Names to those items and reference them directly.

```
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="ComboItemAll">
   ...
</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="ComboItemGeneral">
   ...
</ComboBoxItem>
```

and the in the Button Click event:

```
if (ComboItemAll.IsSelected)
{
   ...
}
else if (ComboItemGeneral.IsSelected)
{
   ...
}
```

alternatively, you could also get this information from your ComboBox "Type":

```
var selectedItem = Type.SelectedItem;
if (selectedItem.Name.StartsWith("ComboItemAll"))
{
   ...
}
else if (selectedItem.Name.StartsWith("ComboItemGeneral"))
{
   ...
}
```

**For MVVM** (Edit):

Xaml (View):

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{CustomItems}" ItemTemplate={StaticResource CustomItemsTemplate} />
```

Xaml (Resource):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomItemsTemplate">
   <StackPanel
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomPropertyFromCustomClass}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

VM:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public ViewModel()
   {
      CustomItems = new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>();
      CustomItems.Add(new CustomClass() { "All" });
      CustomItems.Add(new CustomClass() { "General" });
   }

   private ObservableCollection<CustomClass> customItems = null;
   public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> CustomItems
   {
      get { return customItems; }
      set
      {
         if (object.Equals(value, customItems) == false)
         {
            customItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => CustomItems);
         }
      }
   }

   private CustomClass selectedCustomItem = null;
   public CustomClass SelectedCustomItem
   {
      get { return selectedCustomItem; }
      set
      {
         if (object.Equals(value, selectedCustomItem) == false)
         {
            selectedCustomItem= value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedCustomItem);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You should never reference your combobox directly from the ViewModel. Everything in your ViewModel should be related to data manipulation and know nothing of the View (aka ComboBox).

Everything else should be done in the view. If you need to access the ComboBox, you need you ask yourself why, and can I do that logic in the XAML through templates and bindings?

Comment: Thank You for answering, I am using MVVM pattern, and button click code is in my ViewModel,How can I access combobox in ViewModel?